# In Java, is it efficient to use Thread.sleep(1) for an idle thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep

I have a main loop in my thread, and part of it tests for if an idle boolean is true. If it is, it will call `Thread.sleep(1)` upon each iteration of the loop. Is this an efficient way to go about doing this? My goal is for the thread to take minimal CPU usage when idle.

Comment: Won't it take time for the system to constantly swap threads this way?  It does require processing power for the thread manager to do its job, and you're asking it to do that job every millisecond.

Comment: That's one thing I suspected might happen, but I wasn't sure at the time. It sounds like `wait` and `notifyAll` will do the job just fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.  Use [`Object.wait`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) instead and make sure you synchronize on the object containing the boolean.  If you don't synchronize and the `boolean` is not `volatile`, you have no memory barrier so there is no guarantee that the polling thread will see the change to the `boolean`.

According to the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28long%29):

> This method causes the current thread (call it T) to place itself in the wait set for this object and then to relinquish any and all synchronization claims on this object. **Thread T becomes disabled for thread scheduling purposes and lies dormant** until one of four things happens:
>
> - Some other thread invokes the `notify` method for this object and thread T happens to be arbitrarily chosen as the thread to be awakened.
> - Some other thread invokes the `notifyAll` method for this object.
> - Some other thread interrupts thread T.
> - ...

so the thread will take no CPU while it is waiting to be notified.

The code below is a simple idle flag with a `waitUntilIdle` method that your `main` method can call and a `setIdle` method that can be called by another thread.

```
public class IdleFlag {
  private boolean idle;

  public void waitUntilIdle() throws InterruptedException {
    synchronized (this) {
      while (true) {
        // If the flag is set, we're done.
        if (this.idle) { break; }
        // Go to sleep until another thread notifies us.
        this.wait();
      }
    }
  }

  public void setIdle() {
    synchronized (this) {
      this.idle = true;
      // Causes all waiters to wake up.
      this.notifyAll();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Though it will work, what is the reason for `while(true)` outside the sync?  It will just end up releasing the lock and reacquiring after the wait (then re releasing).  As apposed to having the `while(true)` within the sync, acquire/release semantics (only once) for each time the wait is notified (regularly or spuriously).

Comment: Well I guess my point is that you can simply `while` within the sync in which you wouldn't incur the extra release/acquire by doing it outside. You're right it does no functional harm and the performance impact is probably negligible.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Mike Samuel, yet I would like to recommend that you use the [concurrent lock packages...](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html)

Continue with mike's paradigm just replace his locking with that introduced in Java 5

More specifically you can use [Condition's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) await methods - those that take timeouts. That way you can, for example, log a message every so often - a message which will help you debug infinite waits. You might also want to perform some rollback logic if the await timesout...

Comment: There is a version of `wait` that takes a timeout, so if you just want to get CPU time every so often to log, that using the `wait(timeout)` call is easier than introducing `Condition`s.

Comment: @John Haager - thanks for the insight, I am ashamed to say that I had not been aware of that

Comment: Still - conditions are related to Locks, and they allow you to do more interesting things than simple syncs

Comment: Haven't looked closely at Conditions, but for what the question originally asked, the basic Thread synchronization seems like a reasonable approach.